# Jquery animate when div size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So I know about slideUp, slideDown, hide, show and how I can animate them. However I am currently using html replacement based on dynamic input. So my input changes so I take my string and make the html of my div change. This works however when the div pops up instantly. Is there a way to animate it to make it smoother?

```
var myHtml = '<h1> this is some text loaded dynamically</h1>';
$('#usersContent').html(myHtml);
```

My only thought so far would be to instantly .hide() the div, then do a slideDown(), any ideas?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question...

Comment: hide the div first and then load content with .html() and now show the div however you want. :)